# How to handle content-security-policy (CSP) while injecting iframe into a webpage?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm attempting to build a chrome browser extension, that whenever the chrome-extension icon is clicked, injects onto the current page an iframe that that then renders inside it an angular application that is packaged into the chrome extension itself (i.e. not from external source). I've got it working except I am unable to get past the CSP violations.

manifest.json

```
  {
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "name": "My Extension",
      "description": "injects iframe in all pages on command",
      "version": "1.0",
      "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "debugger", "*://*.google.com/*", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "notifications"],
      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "defualt_title": "My Extension"
      },
      "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
      },
      "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://*.googleapis.com/*; object-src 'self' https://*.googleapis.com/*",
      "web_accessible_resources": [
        "index.html",
        "assets/css/*",
        "assets/js/*",
        "assets/fonts/*"
      ]
    }
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "contentScript.js"});
});
```

contentScript.js

```
'use strict';
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL("index.html");
iframe.id = 'myExtension';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

console.log('content script has executed');
```

Then you have your typical index.html for and vanilla Angular application:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://*.googleapis.com/* 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self' https://*.googleapis.com/*"> -->
  <title>My Extension</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="height: 400px; overflow: hidden;">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

After building and testing the extension in the browser I get the following errors:

[image]

I've researched and researched and none of the answers I've found seem applicable to my particular use case, or CSP is too nuanced for me to understand the applicability of those solutions. Any help resolving this would be legendary!

Comment: To me, it looks like the page you try to inject your data to blocks that through its own CSP settings. Can you try to run your extension on a page that has no CSP configured?

Comment: @NicoHaase, just tried it on a dev site that I have hosted, where I don't believe I have CSP configured. I'm very new to CSP, but I know I never configured it on the said site, and I got the same errors. Could this be chrome enforce this?

Comment: Those errors are generated inside the iframe so they aren't related to page CSP. The problem here is that your CSP in manifest.json is incorrect and doesn't allow you to load remote scripts into the privileged extension context. You can either fix your CSP string by removing http and `*` so only the host name is listed or remove CSP altogether and include the scripts with your extension package, which is much much much better (you should **never** load a remote script into extension context).

Comment: @wOxxOm, could you show me in an example or point me to one?

Comment: You can inspect any site like github in devtools network panel to see a valid CSP. Or check the documentation/tutorials. Anyway, like I said, it's an inferior approach.

Comment: @wOxxOm gotcha. I read through it before, and it wasn't too straight forward. But after another read through the docs, it now makes sense. You are correct it isn't the best way forward, and I'm packaging with the extension. Thanks!

Comment: @E.E.33 can you please share your solution please? I face with this issue as well. I  inject an iframe from content script in my chrome extension, but get the following error:
Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://app.getbeamer.com". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.